# Bad bluetooth headset audio quality on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth

I've seen few related topic but still not found any solution that works for me.
I've got:
JBL Tune 700BT Bluetooth headset
Lenovo T460s with Intel 8260 Bluetooth
Windows 10 version 2004

When Stereo mode picked for JBL headset everything sounds fine. But when it comes to handsfree mode sound if awefull. It cracks, beeps and can't hear anything properly. By the way at this time also my BR mice starts lagging. i've already tried different BT drivers but nothing helps. I've tried this headset on another Win10 laptop and connecting to phone. Both times it was ok. Connecting another BT headset works fine too. Don't know that to try next.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the OP's question, I think the quality issues step from "hands free" audio devices go through a different codec and/or sampling rate.  Just set your Windows Default Communication Device as the Stereo headset.

**For everyone else, coming to this question wondering why your expensive headphones sound terrible for music** (including "tinny", "low fidelity", or just "not as good as my phone"), then read on.

Your Bluetooth headphones might be identifying itself to Windows 10 as two different devices.  First as a "Stereo" or "Music" device.  It may also identify itself as an "AG", or "Hands Free" device.

You can inspect the associated audio devices from the Windows Control Panel. Select the "Sound" icon in Control Panel.  A pop-up window will appear showing what devices Windows knows about and which ones are active.

[image]

If you see the Hands-free AG device selected and the Stereo/Music device unselected, right click on the Stereo device in the list and select "Set as Default Device".  That's pretty much all you have to do.

[image]

The result is that Stereo/Music device is now selected and audio should instantly improve.  You can also set the device as the "Default Communication Device" if it's a headset you want to use it in a video call. Most apps like Teams, Skype, Zoom, etc... will pick the default communication device.

Selection in the list should now look like this:

[image]

Alternatively, if you click the little speaker icon in your systray and subsequently click the device name above the slider bar, a pop-up list appears.  What makes it confusing is that the two devices with similar names may not be next to each other or the long device name may be possibly truncated.  Search the entire list for the correct entry for your headphones as music device - then select it.

[image]

Comment: Setting "Headphones" as primary communication device, will prevent you from using it as a headset. This means no more talking to people.